# Unable to modify the control collection

Tags: c#, webforms

I'm trying to add a Link to a webform page from a user control.  The CSS file contains the styling used by the control.  When I try, I get the following exception:

> The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load,
>   PreRender or Unload phase

So, when can anything be added to the controls collection?  Seems to me the exception message suggests that all options are off the table.  Here's the code:

```
public partial class AddNoteDlg : UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterFiles();
    }


    private void RegisterFiles()
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(GetType(), "addNoteDlgComponent-1.0.0.js", ResolveUrl("~/Shared/scripts/js/addNoteDlgComponent-1.0.0.js"));

        var css = new HtmlLink();
        css.Href = ResolveUrl("~/Shared/css/addNoteDlg-0.0.1.css");
        css.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
        css.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
        css.Attributes["media"] = "all";

        Page.Controls.Add(css);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, stuck the link tag in the user control markup, as there is no difference, practically speaking.

(The original motivation for doing it programmatically was so I could add it to the header, with `Page.Header.Controls.Add(css)`, allowing me to keep all CSS links in the header.)